# Difference between Kelvin and Celsius in dynamic thermal behavior of MOSFETs

Tags: ltspice, spice, thermal, fet

I am trying to understand the temperature behavior at the junction level and this Application Note "AN_201712_PL11_001" from Infineon describes the process.

The problem is that I have a hard time understanding when I can use degrees Celsius or Kelvin as a temperature control.

[image]

I understand that when we talk about temperature difference "delta_T", both Celsius and Kelvin are equal but when I need to use as a temperature-junction or temperature-case control why is it Celsius and not Kelvin?

Also, what does the Voltage-Controlled Current Source "Gs" (in series with FET source) actually do? In the SPICE code I see that it takes the Tj node value and then subtract 25 from it

[image]

[image]

Comment: For your 2nd question, the `Gs` is basically a resistor that varies with the junction temperature. When `Tj` is 25, then it reduces to `Rs-Rm`.

Comment: The voltages being described here have nothing to do with real voltages in any component or circuit -- they are just part of the simulated model, and provide an awkward way to control some parameters of the simulation. Because "temperature of case" and "temperature of junction" are absolute temperatures (not temperature differences), it's more natural for most people to think of them in Celsius instead of Kelvin.

Comment: @GlennWillen I would say it's generally more natural to think of absolute temperatures in Kelvin, since that way you don't need an additive offset factor in your calculations....

Comment: T_case is likely to be close to ambient / room temperature, though. So it will be a human-scale temperature, much closer to 0 C than 0 K. (T_junction will be higher, I imagine, but even so, people usually quote junction temperatures in Celsius or Fahrenheit, not Kelvin.)

Comment: @GlennWillen I understand that on the thermal model the K and C are relative but my question is: if Gs behaves like a resistor which makes sense because in reality Rds_ON increase with temperature so my question is: if Gs takes the value from the Tj node to alter its Value depending on temperature, then Kelvin and Celsius shouldn't not be the same, right?